# Java ScheduledExecutorService producer\consumer

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer, java.util.concurrent, blockingqueue

I have the next project:

Spring(3.2)-based Web application(Tomcat 7), in background I have several tasks.

I have a queue with some information for processing. This queue is updating periodically(but just when it empty).

Also I have several threads that enqueue periodically data from this queue and process.

For scheduling I wanted to use ScheduledExecutorService.

I have several problems\questions:

1. How to keep this queue? As I think it should be global. Should I make it static in some "holder" class? Won't be this a poor desing?
2. Where will be the good place for initializing this queue and all the task with ScheduledExecutorService? Is ServletContextLoadingListener a good place for it? Are there any ways to init this with Spring?
3. Should I use several ScheduledExecutorService instances if I need to control the number of consumer threads exactly?
4. Will ArrayBlockingQueue be good for this case?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use an ordinary class and let spring manage it with the scope `singleton`.
2. You can configure the bean with an `init-method` in spring configuration or implement the `InitializingBean` interface in your class.
3. The thread number for `ScheduledExecutorService` is configurable via the constructor arguments. If you have tasks of several types and want to run them in separate thread pools, you can use multiple `ScheduledExecutorService` instances. However, if all your task are of the same type, I don't see the need for multiple `ScheduledExecutorService` instances.
4. The `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` provided within JDK has an internal working queue of class `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.DelayedWorkQueue.DelayedWorkQueue`(and it is not configurable). I am not sure where do you put the ArrayBlockingQueue.

Comment: Thanks, about 4th item, I need to have a updatable queue with some amount of data for processing by worker-threads, as I understand DelayedWorkQueue is inside ScheduledExecutorService and it is for worker-threads that I submit there.